# What is the reason that I can't go out the for-loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

guys.
This is my first question in stackoverflow.
This code is a code for program solving and the question is asking to find the smallest sequence that has no neighboring redundant sequence in it. The input is the sequence's length, and the sequence should have only 1, 2, 3.
For example, if I input 7, the output should be 1213121.
Now, my real question is about the for-loop.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int mini = 0xffffff;
int n;
string s1, s2;

bool isgood(string s)
{
    for(int i=1;i<=s.size()/2;i++)
    {
        s1 = "";
        s2 = "";
        for(int j=s.size()-1;j>=s.size()-i;j--)
        {
            s1 += s[j];
        } //this works ok
        for(int k=s.size()-1-i;k>=s.size()-i-i;k--)//Problem
        {
            cout<<"*** "<<k<<endl; //I printed the k, and it printed 0, -1, -2, -3......, and it didn't go out.
            s2 += s[k];
        }
        if(s1.compare(s2)==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void f(string s)
{
    if(s.size()==n)
    {
        if(mini>stoi(s))
        {
            mini=stoi(s);
        }
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int r=1;r<=3;r++)
        {
            if(isgood(s+char(r+'0'))==true)
            {
                f(s+char(r+'0'));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &n);
    f("1");
    printf("%d", mini);
}
```

as you see in my code, there is a for, but it doesn't go out.
when I changed it to for(int k=s.size()-1-i;k>s.size()-i-i-1;k--), it didn't made the exact goal, but the program worked.
Please help me what is the problem, and how can I solve it.

Comment: This question could use a few more example outcomes. Why are you passing "1" to f initially ?I can't read your code.. and I find it difficult to understand what you try to achieve. What's a "neighboring redundant sequence" ? And b.t.w. what makes you think we're all "guys"..

Comment: Note that the `size()` function returns a `size_t`, which is *unsigned*. So, you may have issues with `s.size() - 1 - i` when `s` is only 1 character long (and `i` is more than zero).

Comment: @Goodies       oh, if I made you to feel bad, I really apologize to you. I thought that "guys" means the people in this community.

Comment: @AdrianMole Oh I followed your advice and made the program roll OK. But, I can't understand some points. In my program, isgood function always has more than 2 characters. But why s.size() is not allowed?

Comment: The problem is in the comparison between signed (like `k` or `j`) and unsigned (like `s.size()-i-i`) types. The exact issue will depend on the relative sizes of the `int` and `size_t` types. But there are also other issues in your code, I think.